# Get ony by one the results from find/locate

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, locate

How can I get 1 by 1 the results of a command like

```
# locate file.txt
/home/alex/file.txt
/backup/file.txt
```

What I want to do is to make an interactive script where to ask: `Which of the following files would you like to copy/recover? [1],[2]:`

Example:

```
filetorecover.txt
_________________
   file.txt
   file1.txt
   ...

./recover filestorecover.txt /home/alex/data/
file.txt could not be located at /home/alex/data, but it was locate here:
[1] /home/alex/files/
[2] /backup/file.txt
```

- filestorecover => is the file that contains file to look for
- /home/alex/files/ => is the main folder where to look for and if the file is not located there, then do a `locate file.txt`

So, mainly I am looking for a way of grabbing those X results from find or locate one by one for the late use as explained above.

### UPDATE

Is it possible to see the most common path for find/locate's result? I mean if I have 6 files located at `/backup/` and 2 at `/home/alex/files/` I would like to set, or ask if they what to get all the files from the most common folder, `/backup/`!

This is meant when I have more than X files (ex: 10), because sometimes I can get up to hundreds of results and I can't go 1 by 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use awk and read.

```
# list of files in temp file
choices=$(mktemp -t choices.XXXXX)
find . -name "file.txt") > $choices

# choices with number prefix
cat $choices | awk '{print "[" NR "]" $0}'

# prompt
echo "Choose one"
read num

# find choice
choice=$( cat $choices | awk "{if (NR==$num){print \$0}}" )
echo "You choose $choice"
```

Comment: Ok it works, thanks @Adam ... but please check my question's update

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bash, you can use the built-in arrays like:

```
# Get all the files
files=`find . -name "file.txt"`
# Put them into an array
declare -a afiles
afiles=( ${files} )

# Output filenames
for (( i = 0; i < ${#afiles[@]}; i += 1 ));
do
    printf "[%d] %s\n" ${i} ${afiles[$i]}
done
```

(The declare is not neccessary but IMHO it is a good comment saying that `afiles` is an array.)

Using arrays has the advantage that you can access the filename after the user entered some number with `${afiles[${number}]}`.

Comment: thanks for your solution... testing it now! I wrote an update, please check it out!

Comment: Your 'Update' is a complete new question. So please finish this one first and create a new.

Answer (score 1):

For your update

```
#paths in order
find . -name '*.txt' | awk '{gsub(/\/[^/]*$/,"");path[$0]+=1} END {for (i in path) print path[i]" "i}' | sort -rg | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Use what has already been posted for the rest